# Hide/Show Overlay on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I currently have an Overlay on my page which fades in when I click certain Navigation elements such as search/dropdown.

My problem is that if I click the dropdown, then click the Search menu item it fades out the overlay and breaks by showing the overlay and no search bar.

> If the overlay is already open, you don't need to fade
>   it in, just fade it out when you click something else.

I've added a Variable to check if it's already open, but obviously this gets troublesome with 'FadeToggle'. I've tried a lot of combinations with this but can't seem to get it to the above.

```
var overlay = false;

$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  if(overlay == false) {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(150);
    overlay = true;
  }
})

$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  if(overlay == true) {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut(150);
    overlay = false;
  }
})

$( "#searchToggle, #mobileSearchToggle" ).click(function() {
  $('.search-bar').toggleClass( "open" );
  $('body').toggleClass("noScroll");
  $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');

  if(overlay == false) {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(150);
  }

});
```

Comment: can you also post your html  snippets

Comment: @JMkelley - With condition `overlay == false`, `fadeToggle` will always behave like `fadeIn`. Will there be any discrepancy with this?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Unsure what you mean.